# References for Coefficient Quivers

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, definition, quiver

I would like to study about **Coefficient Quivers**, but I cannot find a good reference.
I could find many papers working with coefficient quivers, but none of them give a
book or a "initial" paper with the definition and (basic) properties of coefficient quivers.

Can someone help me by giving some (good) references where I can learn about coefficient quiver?

Any suggestion is welcome!!

Comment: By "coefficient quiver", do you mean the object defined, for instnace, in [this paper by Ringel](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379597100465)?

Comment: Hello @Pierre-GuyPlamondon, it is precisely what I mean. I gave a quick look in the paper by Ringel. I will read it more carefully, but if you know more references about the subject I will be glad to hear from you.